# App won't show up in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I've just installed django on my mac os x snow leopard and got some issues with it. 
I just made a very simple project that only contains a simple app. 
The app contains just one model and it's a task. When running syncdb the table for tasks is created without any problems and I'm requested to create new user. 
Everything works fine and I can log in and so on but my app is not showing up.

Here is some code from my project.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'work.todo',
)
```

**todo/admin.py**

```
from work.todo import Task
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Task)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    # (r'^work/', include('work.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs' 
    # to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:
    (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

**todo/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Task(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    done = models.BooleanField()
```

Maybe it's worth to mention that there is a `__init__.py` in both work and the work/todo folder.

Cheers,
nandarya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In todo/admin.py:

```
from work.todo.models import Task
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Task)
```

You forgot `models` in your import statement :)

Comment: Trust me, you don't want these eyes. Just ask the guys who sit next to me at work :)